# how ot add a kinesis stream to trigger lambda function

Tags: serverless-framework

When configuring a lambda function in the serverless framework, i am trying to add a kinesis stream as the event course:

here is the snippet from serverless.yml

```
functions:
  Foo:
    handler: handler.foo
    events:
      - stream:
        arn: arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:783995676505:stream/search-helper
        batchSize: 100
        startingPosition: LATEST
        enabled: false
```

The deployment via "serverless deploy" is successful however the trigger does not get added to the function configuration.

I checked the yml file using a yml validatior and there are no errors. What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

The yml file needs to be indented just after `stream:`

```
functions: 
  Foo:
    handler: handler.foo
    events:
      - stream:
          arn: arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:783995676505:stream/search-helper
          batchSize: 100
          startingPosition: LATEST
          enabled: false
```

See the Serveless Framework examples at https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/streams/